# how to export ejs object to the public directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am creating a node express app and have ejs as my templating system.

Now in my `new.ejs` file, I want to clear it out with javascripts so it will be purely html .

I have a script inside my `new.ejs` like this.

```
    <script> 
          let amount;

          function calculate(){
                  let numOfPersons = Number($('#numOfPersons').val());
                  let tourPrice = Number("<%= tour.price %>"); //ejs object here

                  let totalPrice = numOfPersons * tourPrice
                  $("#total").val(totalPrice);
                  amount = totalPrice
          }   
</script>
```

Now I tried transferring it to my `public/javascript/calculate.js` file but it is saying that `tour is not defined` because the `<%= tour %>` is not imported inside the `calculate.js` file.

to clean up my code, I tried this inside my `new.ejs`

```
 <script src="javascripts/calculate.js">
  export default "<%=  tour %>" //this is the name of my object
</script>
```

and inside `calculate.ejs`

```
import {tour} from "../../views/booking/new.js";

let amount;


          function calculate(){
                  let numOfPersons = Number($('#numOfPersons').val());
                  let tourPrice = Number("<%= tour.price %>");

                  let totalPrice = numOfPersons * tourPrice
                  $("#total").val(totalPrice);
                  amount = totalPrice
          }
```

But it is not working. I tried consulting the MDN for Import and Export and I think my syntax is correct but not working.

What did I do wrong? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you export as default you don't need {} around the variable. Try removing that

in your code
 `import {tour} from "../../views/booking/new.js"`

but there is no file named new.js i think, that should be new.ejs try with this if it don't work please let me know. More over if you want to pass any variable from ejs page to server most of the time we will be  binding the value in body parameters and using that where it is directed to / required.